# Angularjs ng-repeat duplicates in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some inputs in ng-repeat:

```
How many ingredients? <input type = "number" placeholder="number of ingredients" ng-model="mealCtrl.numberIng">

<li ng-repeat="i in mealCtrl.getNumber(mealCtrl.numberIng) track by $index">
   Name: <input type = "text" placeholder="nazwa składnika" ng-model="mealCtrl.ingredient[i].name">
   Manufacturer: <input type = "text" placeholder="manufacturer of ingredient" ng-model="mealCtrl.ingredient[i].producer">
   Weight: <input type = "number" placeholder="weight in grams" ng-model="mealCtrl.ingredient[i].weight">
   Description: <input type = "text" placeholder="description" ng-model="mealCtrl.ingredient[i].description"><br />
</li>
```

and here I have code in my controller:

```
.controller('AddMealController', function(Meals, Meal) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.meal = new Meal();
    vm.getNumber = function(num) {
        return new Array(num);   
    }
    vm.saveMeal = function() {
        vm.meal.ingredients = [vm.ingredient[0], vm.ingredient[1], vm.ingredient[2], vm.ingredient[3], vm.ingredient[4], vm.ingredient[5]];
        Meals.add(vm.meal);
        vm.meal = new Meal();
    }
})
```

But vm.getNumber returns to me an array with correct size, but all the same values, and every repeted input in ng-repeat has the same "i" value. I want an "i" value of 0, 1, 2 if I choose 3 in mealCtrl.numberIng. How to do it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved your issue on my way. [but hope maybe it will help You. see example](https://plnkr.co/edit/9Cg67nb4gqpDgatqpRkt?p=preview)

**JS**

```
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.ingredients = [];

  $scope.xxxxxxx =function(num) {
      for(let i=0; i < num; i++){
        $scope.ingredients.push({name:'',producer:'',weight:0,description:''})
      }
    }

});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    How many ingredients? 
    <input type = "number" ng-change="xxxxxxx(numberIng)" placeholder="number of ingredients" ng-model="numberIng">{{numberIng}}

    <li ng-repeat="x in ingredients">
   Name: <input type = "text" placeholder="nazwa składnika" ng-model="x.name">
   Manufacturer: <input type = "text" placeholder="manufacturer of ingredient" ng-model="x.producer">
   Weight: <input type = "number" placeholder="weight in grams" ng-model="x.weight">
   Description: <input type = "text" placeholder="description" ng-model="x.description"><br />
</li>
{{ingredients}}
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you give some number to numberIng input and then you change it to other number, it's gona no change the numbers of ng-repeat but add a new one. So if you give 2 and change it to 3, there will be 5 ng-repeats. Try it in you program.

Comment: I know!! Just put another $scope.ingredients = []; insaide the function xxxxxx to reset this array inside function,
 and will be works just fine. Thank you, It's working:)))

Comment: Nothing Super fancy. Just Initialize ingredients array on every numberIng Change. See Demo Here  'https://plnkr.co/edit/bDx3Sl9hFqyuaJ3SOCBz?p=preview

Comment: I didn't say it's something super fancy, just something normal that works:)) I put your code in my app and it's works like I wanted, so thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome brother.

Answer (score 0):

try to create an array of Meals and inside each meal to create an array of ingredients like that:

```
meals = [
{
id: 1,
name:'a'
ingredients:[ { id:10,name:'aaa'},{id:11,name:'bbb'}]
},
{
id: 2,
name:'b'
ingredients:[ { id:12,name:'ccc'},{id:13,name:'ddd'}]
}
]
```

and try this ng-repeat option:

```
<li ng-repeat="meal in meals">
    {{meal.name}}
  <div ng-repeat="ingredient in meal.ingredients">
    {{ingredient.name}}
  </div>
</li>
```